# PHP: Store Languages and their Native Names

Tags: php, arrays, localization

The below is in regard to displaying a language switcher on my website.

I am currently using language codes (as key) and language names (as values) in an array, so they can be called later and displayed on a website.

```
array (
    'en' => 'English',
    'fr' => 'French',
    'de' => 'German'
);
```

I am wanting to upgrade my coding to allow each language to display in it's native text. For example, "English" could also be written as "Anglais" (in French) and "Englisch" in German.

So my question is what is the most efficient way of doing this?  Would I construct a new array for this? Or should I use a built-in PHP function that provides these language names?  Building from scratch is perfectly fine if needed, but I need some type of guidance on how the array construction would look.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how many languages you have this could get quite messy :) May I suggest that if you need to translate the word English to it's French equivalent that you probably won't care about English. Displaying the language in it's native language though would be more useful. Without knowing you use case perhaps you have a perfectly good reason for this. This package will give you the English equivalent and the native name. https://github.com/rinvex/language

Comment: Great package @Augma thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do anything more than a few single words, you should use [`gettext()` to provide localization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php).

```
<?php
bindtextdomain("myApp", "./locale");
textdomain("myApp");
$langs = array (
    'en' => _('English'),
    'fr' => _('French'),
    'de' => _('German')
);
```

Then you'd create a messages file for each language in the `./locale/` directory specified above. For example the French one would look like this:

```
msgid "English"
msgstr "anglais"
msgid "French"
msgstr "français"
msgid "German"
msgid "allemande"
```

This is a standard library, used not just in PHP. There are many programs that will scan your PHP files looking for `_("text")` and automatically create message files.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly used an multidimensional array to store names in differetn language.

something like

```
$lang = [
   'en' => [
      'en' => 'english',
      'fr' => 'french'
   ],
   'fr' => [
      'en' => 'anglais',
      'fr' => 'francais'
   ],
];
```

So you can get the names by doing

```
echo $lang['fr']['fr'] //francais
echo $lang['fr']['en'] //anglais
```

Can be a pain if you start having all the language in the world but can handle bi-lingual at least.

On the native way i have no experience but you might want to start by looking at http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php.

> Returns an appropriately localized display name for language of the
>   inputlocale

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php for the long story.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
echo Locale::getDisplayLanguage('locale', 'in_locale');
```

In array use it like this:

```
array (
    'en' => Locale::getDisplayLanguage('en', 'en'),
    'fr' => Locale::getDisplayLanguage('fr', 'fr'),
    'de' => Locale::getDisplayLanguage('de', 'de'),
);
```

[Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php) for php manual.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Augwa suggestion to use `rinvex/language` package here:

https://github.com/rinvex/language

I have exported the data in the following array:

https://gist.github.com/rafasashi/fd1a08c1b72a54e905b665a35e548509